# How to infer Tuples while preserving type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA%20gVgewJYDsA8MDOIC2AjBAG0yggA9gIUATEgbQEMUQAaKAOk82ACdUBzOgF0hAPigBeKAG8AUFCh0YAawggoqWNnxESDEirWkKVWoqasOnVADMIPKDwjchUAPxREqNE%205sA5AD0-uIAXFAoEABu9kLhhiB0AAxCANyyAL7psoGBUABSyCgk3Hwo-CRRSAxQ1BCESDhIlNTyoJCeRWgAyrwCJOSUNCQAShAM1AgohCBoAII8PAyzpQJQAD4RAK749qKibAAi9Y3N9sZDZqvl4lK9ZRUXpvRC8u5Q-v5v4ff9T8OKa78DbbXY8V4KDwAAwAJNJfuVMMkhBkod8oAjHoNno5xpNpuo6ECQSgdnh7GxOOxbOcxtx-mYFksVn1yiSyXsIe9YfDWRVkRk4ccGk1KDxBdIvOg6cAjidRXtUeigekgA)

The Code:

```
type _join<_symbols extends [any, ...string[]]> = {
  [_key in _symbols as _key extends [any, ...infer rest] ? join<rest, '/'> : never]: _key[0];
};
```

The `rest` value should be inferred to as `string[]`, but is instead inferred as `unknown[]`. Why is this? The output works as expected, so the logic should be sound. I'm assuming it's some quirk of TS's syntax I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in your assumption that the logic is sound here but are hitting a limitation of the `infer` keyword.

The information from the *constraint* of `_symbols` is *not* carried over to the inferred type `rest` as described in [#21937](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21937). Types inferred *from a generic type* with the `infer` keyword often do not have any further information associated with them and appear as opaque generic types.

For this example, the inference of `rest` is not fully opaque. Since the position of the inference is a variadic tuple type, it is assumed by the compiler that `rest` must extend `unknown[]` which is what you see in the error message.

---

I found [this proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51108) which, *if implemented at some point*, could give the compiler the ability to also factor in the constraints when inferring types using `infer`. For now, the need for this feature is limited as [PR#48112](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48112) introduced a way to explicitly provide a constraint when using the `infer` keyword.

```
type _join<_symbols extends [any, ...string[]]> = {
  [_key in _symbols as _key extends [any, ...infer rest extends string[]] 
    ? join<rest, '/'> 
    : never
  ]: _key[0];
};
```

This is looks to be somewhat redundant; but for the foreseeable future we will need it to solve these issues.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA+gVgewJYDsA8MDOIC2AjBAG0yggA9gIUATEgbQEMUQAaKAOk82ACdUBzOgF0hAPigBeKAG8AUFCh0YAawggoqWNnxESDEirWkKVWoqasOnVADMIPKDwjdjlGiW58UgkVAD8UIioaE7cbADkAPTh4gBcUCgQAG72QvGGIHQADEIA3LIAvvmykZFQAFLIKB68AiRJSAxQ1BCESDhIlNSyoJCBVWgAyrXeJORuZgBKEAzUCCiEIGgAgjw8DEueAlAAPgkArvj2oqJsACKt7Z32rqY1XvziUsMPYybuikLy-lDh4d-xF51W4fOhbby7A5HHhfBQBAAGABJpEDRtkhAV4QCoKj+G8JiQnLN5otFOD+JCUIc8PY2Jx2LYbtMXOM7lBVutNiMKXsqdDRLCfkiUdzMOiCsiLm0OpQeBLpEF0MzgOdLjLjpjseT8kA)